# Google App Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Trying to get this javascript code:

```
result = response.return || response;
```

to work in Google Sheet Script and I get error: Missing name after . operator

The full code section is:

```
try {
                var response = JSON.parse(body);

                if(response.error) {
                    error = response.error;
                }
                else {
                    result = response.return || response;
                }
            }
            catch(e) {
                error = "Error parsing server response: " + e.message;
            }
```

How to I get this to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
return
```

Is a keyword in JavaScript. You need to change the response object. Rename 'return' to something like returnedData or Returned or even Return [capital R] will work.

Comment: can be also done more easily without renaming. use the alternate syntax response["return"]