# Using the Google Classroom API, is it possible to change a grade without a turn in?

Tags: google-classroom

I'm looking to create an assignment in Google classroom's gradebook, then automatically grade it (without a student turning in an assignment).

This seems to indicate that this is feasible, but the conversation there is a bit jumbled: [Google Apps Script to turn in, grade, and return a Google Classroom Assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48480059/google-apps-script-to-turn-in-grade-and-return-a-google-classroom-assignment)

To utilize the PATCH endpoint to grade an assignment, you must have a submission id.  https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.courseWork.studentSubmissions/patch . And at first glance, you wouldn't have a submission id if the student hasn't submitted anything.  However, the previous stackoverflow link shows that this may be possible.  They appear to get it from the submissions list.  https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.courseWork.studentSubmissions/list . However, if this were the case, then the submissions list would need to include submission IDs for students who haven't even submitted the assignment yet.

Is this the case, or am I missing another way of going about this?

Comment: Were you able to use the PATCH endpoint? If so, can you tell me what you're using in the request querystring and body? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The submissions list does include submission IDs even for students who haven't submitted the assignment.